# Exploit in bash script parameter possible?

Tags: shell, security, regular-expression, php

I want to pass an e-mail address from a web form to a bash script. I'm using the following regex:

```
/[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}/
```

Is this sufficient? Or could one embed an exploit?

The script is called from PHP:

```
system('/usr/local/bin/script.sh "$email"');
```

Comment: Well done even for asking.  I don't see any exploit potential but you may reject some valid email addresses and accept some invalid ones.  Oh—and you should **anchor your regex**.

Comment: @Wildcard Indeed the lack of anchoring makes the regexp useless as a security test!

Comment: This could be a valid email address `"the doctor"@gallifrey.com`. Note the quoted space in the username component.

Comment: at what point are you worried about an exploit? The subject-line says 'bash', so is the concern around expansion while passing $email as a (quoted) argument to script.sh, or script.sh's handling of the passed value, or the stringency of the (presumably PHP-based) regex, or ???

Comment: It is not clear how the regexp is used inside your script. For a good analyses, please provide the relevant parts of your script.

Answer (score 1):

You may sanitize and validate the email address in PHP, which will be quicker and safer than calling a shell script. Calling a shell script with unsanitized data from a web service will just add yet another thing that can break.

```
$sanitized_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
if (filter_var($sanitized_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo "This sanitized email address is considered valid.\n";
    echo "Before: $email\n";
    echo "After:  $sanitized_email\n";    
} else {
    echo "This sanitized email address is considered invalid.\n";
}
```

Example above adapted from [examples on the PHP.net site](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php).